# Trying to get lowest integers

Tags: java

So I have 4 list,
I want to find out which list.size(); is the lowest.
I can find the lowest but some turn out to be the same, this is
what I have.

```
              if(EAmount < DAmount && EAmount < GAmount && EAmount < IAmount){
        FinalDecision = "Emerald";
    }else if(DAmount < EAmount && DAmount < GAmount && DAmount < IAmount){
        FinalDecision = "Diamond";
    }else if(GAmount < EAmount && GAmount < DAmount && GAmount < IAmount){
        FinalDecision = "Gold";
    }else if(IAmount < EAmount && IAmount < DAmount && IAmount < GAmount){
        FinalDecision = "Iron";
    }
```

Though I need it to check for the lowest than pick a random between those two in case. Example, if EAmount and DAmount are both 2, but then Gold and Iron are 3 and 4. I want it so it finds out that EAmount and DAmount are both 2 then pick one of them by random. So all  in all "I want it so it will find the lowest int, if there is more than one of the lowest int pick a random between it." How would I do this? BTW: Its not always going to be so EAmount and DAmount are equal. All of these variables are completely random.

Comment: Why pick a random? Why not choose both as possibilities?

Comment: `EAmount and DAmount are both 2 then pick one of them by random.` Why so?

Comment: You can make your life easier by using a `Map<String, Integer> amounts` to hold all the amounts. Then use e.g. `amounts.get("Diamond")` to get the respective amount from the map. This way you can also use builtin sorting functions etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after lot of logic research i got solution,it works 100% and i tested it

first found minimum sized list's size using treeset

put all list and their sizes into map

iterate map to find all lowest sized list(if there are more than one) using above lowest size as a key and put only those into finallist

then take finalist and take random number using its size

then pass this random number to final list get method get corresponding list randomly.

```
List list1 = new ArrayList();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    List list2 = new ArrayList();
    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(2);
    List list3 = new ArrayList();
    list3.add(1);
    list3.add(2);
    list3.add(1);
    List list4 = new ArrayList();
    list4.add(1);
    list4.add(2);
    list4.add(1);
    list4.add(2);


    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.add(list1.size());
    set.add(list2.size());
    set.add(list3.size());
    set.add(list4.size());

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
    int min = list.get(0);
    System.out.println(min);


    Map<List, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(list1,list1.size());
    map.put(list2,list2.size());
    map.put(list3,list3.size());
    map.put(list4,list4.size());



    List finalList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<List, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getValue().equals(min)){
            finalList.add(entry.getKey());

        }

    }


    int finalKey = new Random().nextInt(finalList.size());

    System.out.println(finalList.get(finalKey));
```

Comment: And how by executing your code I'm going to randomly get either "Emerald" or "Gold"?

Comment: you can see my other post which is complete solution.

Comment: Then you can probably delete the other post :)

Comment: i can not delete as its accepted for partial solution :)

Comment: Can you please either clarify what the difference is between your two answers, or delete one of them?  I haven't gone through and compared them line by line, but they seem very alike to me.  There is an edit feature, for making changes and additions to an answer once you've posted it - there's never a need to have a whole new post just for the additions.

Comment: hey David, i have deleted and edited now to have one post..difference was first was finding lowest integer only it never gives us the list associated with it. but now edited one handles that too..let me know for any doubts

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach your requirements:

1. Define a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which would store `list.size` values and map it to the `Set` of labels (or lists, depeding what you're interested in - not 100% clear from the question). So in your case multimap will store the following:

   `2 -> Set("Diamond", "Emerald")`
   `3 -> Set("Gold")`
   `4 -> Set("Iron")`
2. Find lowest value of all multimap keys.
3. Get the set of labels for the lowest value.
4. Choose one of the labels at random.

Answer (score 0):

First time you need to determine the list sizes and put them in the map. After that you can group the map by the value and set results to another map. For this map you can use a count. Now, this number you should use as a parameter to random.